# Validate uniqueness of composite model fields against form input in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, model

I'm writing a user signup form using Laravel 4 that lets the user input their name in `first_name` and `last_name` fields. During my form input validation, I'd like to check both fields for uniqueness against the composite name `first_name + " " + last_name` from values in the table where this is meant to be saved.

I know you can check for uniqueness against a single field using the `unique` rule, and can even override the field by specifying `unique:tableName,fieldName`.

Ideally I would do something like `unique:tableName,first_name + " " + last_name`, or by specifying something in the model itself, but I haven't been able to find anything on composite/virtual fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up extending the Validator class to define the custom validator rules. I check it on the `first_name` field for my app mainly because I don't want to have to do extra work in generating the full name. Except instead of making it a composite value, which was unnecessary after thinking about the problem, I simply set it to check the `AND` of all the values for the fields specified. You can specify any number of fields, and if one of them doesn't exist in the validator data it will throw an exception. I'm not even sure if this can be accomplished solely with the existing `unique` rule, but it was a good exercise regardless.

```
'first_name' => 'unique_multiple_fields:members,first_name,last_name'
```

My validator subclass code:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as IlluminateValidator;

class CustomValidatorRules extends IlluminateValidator
{
    /**
     * Validate that there are no records in the specified table which match all of the 
     * data values in the specified fields. Returns true iff the number of matching 
     * records is zero.
     */
    protected function validateUniqueMultipleFields( $attribute, $value, $parameters )
    {
        if (is_null($parameters) || empty($parameters)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected $parameters to be a non-empty array.');
        }
        if (count($parameters) < 3) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The $parameters option should have at least 3 items: table, field1, field2, [...], fieldN.');
        }

        // Get table name from first parameter, now left solely with field names.
        $table = array_shift($parameters);

        // Uppercase the table name, remove the 's' at the end if it exists
        // to get the class name of the model (by Laravel convention).
        $modelName = preg_replace("/^(.*)([s])$/", "$1", ucfirst($table));

        // Create the SQL, start by getting only the fields specified in parameters
        $select = $modelName::select($parameters);

        // Generate the WHERE clauses of the SQL query.
        foreach ($parameters as $fieldName) {
            $curFieldVal = ($fieldName === $attribute) ? $value : $this->data[$fieldName];
            if (is_null($curFieldVal)) {
                // There is no data for the field specified, so fail.
                throw new \Exception("Expected `{$fieldName}` data to be set in the validator.");
            }

            // Add the current field name and value
            $select->where($fieldName, '=', $curFieldVal);
        }

        // Get the number of fields found
        $numFound = $select->count();

        return ($numFound === 0);
    }
}
```

In case you're curious, I did get it to work using the composite method I originally was looking at. The code for that is below. Turns out the 'separator' is completely pointless, hence why I ended up refactoring it to use the multiple-fields method specified above.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as IlluminateValidator;

class CustomValidatorRules extends IlluminateValidator
{
    /**
     * Validate that the final value of a set of fields - joined by an optional separator -
     * doesn't match any records in the specified table. Returns true iff the number of
     * matching records is zero.
     */
    protected function validateUniqueComposite( $attribute, $value, $parameters )
    {
        if (is_null($parameters) || empty($parameters)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected $parameters to be a non-empty array.');
        }
        if (count($parameters) < 3) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The $parameters option should have at least 3 items: table, field1, field2, [...], fieldN.');//, [separator].');
        }

        // Get table name from first parameter
        $table = array_shift($parameters);

        // Determine the separator
        $separator = '';
        $lastParam = array_pop($parameters);
        if (! isset($this->data[$lastParam])) {
            $separator = $lastParam;
        }

        // Get the names of the rest of the fields.
        $fields = array();
        foreach ($parameters as $fieldName) {
            array_push($fields, $table . "." . $fieldName);
        }
        $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

        $dataFieldValues = array();
        foreach ($parameters as $fieldName) {
            $curFieldVal = ($fieldName === $attribute) ? $value : $this->data[$fieldName];
            if (is_null($curFieldVal)) {
                throw new \Exception("Expected `{$fieldName}` data.");
            }
            array_push($dataFieldValues, $curFieldVal);
        }
        $compositeValue = implode($separator, $dataFieldValues);

        // Uppercase the table name, remove the 's' at the end if it exists
        // to get the class name of the model (by Laravel convention).
        $modelName = preg_replace("/^(.*)([s])$/", "$1", ucfirst($table));
        $raw = \DB::raw("concat_ws('" . $separator . "', " . $fields . ")");
        $model = new $modelName;

        // Generate the SQL query
        $select = $modelName::where($raw, '=', $compositeValue);
        $numFound = $select->count();

        return ($numFound === 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you set the `$modelName`, you're removing the `s` at the end of the string. This isn't always the correct way to get the singular form (think 'box' => 'boxes'). You can improve that by using `str_plural()` from Laravel ([check the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#strings)). For those using non-english model / table names you should take care of this pluralization (or simply pass the table name to the validation).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll add it to the hotfix queue for this project.

Answer (score 2):

Write you own rule. It can look something like this:

```
'unique_composite:table,field1,field2,field3,...,fieldN'
```

The fields enumerated after the table name will be concatenated and checked against the composite value. The validation rule will look something like this:

```
Validator::extend('unique_composite', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Get table name from first parameter
    $table  = array_shift($parameters);
    $fields = implode(',', $parameters);

    // Build the query that searches the database for matches
    $matches = DB::table($table)
                ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", ' . $fields . ')'), $value)
                ->count();

    // Validation result will be false if any rows match the combination
    return ($matches == 0);
});
```

In your validator you can have something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('full_name' => $firstName + ' ' + $lastName),
    array('full_name' => 'unique_composite:users,first_name,last_name')
);
```

With this rule you can use any number of fields, not just two.

Comment: I'll try this out. Where do I put the code for this validator extension though?

Comment: There isn't really any convention regarding this as long as the file containg the rules is included. For example you could place it in `app/validators.php` and include it in `app/start/global.php` with `require app_path().'/validators.php';`.

Comment: Every variation of the query you provide gives me the following SQL error (postgresql): `Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "composite_value" does not exist`

Comment: Giving you +1 since you put me in the right direction, but see my answer for how I actually solved this.

Comment: The code I posted was not tested, that's why it was throwing errors. I've updated my answer with a tested version that works, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a custom validator, you can also specify more conditions that will be added as "where" clauses to the query and do:

```
'first_name' => 'required|unique:table_name,first_name,null,id,last_name,'.$data['last_name'],
'last_name' => 'required|unique:table_name,last_name,null,id,first_name,'.$data['first_name'],
```

This way, uniqueness of the `first_name` will only be enforced on rows whose `last_name` is equal to the inputted `last_name` (`$data['last_name']` in our example).

Same is true the other way around for the uniqueness of `last_name`.

If you want to force the unique rule to ignore a given ID, just replace `null` with that specific ID.

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique